# KeyUp function working on Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari

Tags: jquery, html

This is my first question on Stack, my apologies if the post is not in the right format.

I have looked through the suggested answers for my question but nothing seems to match the problem that I am facing.

I have two buttons which are disabled by default. Then there is a jQuery which check whether data has been inputted into the text fields in my form. If there is nothing inputted, buttons stay disabled. If there is text - buttons are enabled and form can be submitted.

The buttons are just simple html code

```
<form id="myForm" action="/platformDev/create_subscription.php" method="POST">
        <div class = "productcreate">
        <div data-html="true" class="producttooltip tooltip-custom" title="Enter your product name, include any relevant information. &lt;br /&gt; Include how you count the product, for example; (Each), (Box), (Case) etc">?</div>
        <label style="font-size:14px" class="control-label no-comma"><font color="black"><strong>Product Name</strong></font></label> <span class="required_field">   </span>
        <form autocomplete="off"><input style="" type="text" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control-login" id="inputFieldId" autofocus="autofocus" name="product_name" tabindex="-1"/>     <br/>
    </div>
        <div id=dep_drop><label style="font-size:14px" class="control-label"><font color="black"><strong>Department - <a id="DepForm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DepModal">Add Departments</a></strong></font></label>
        <select class='form-control select_element nc_department_id_new'    name='department_id_new'><option  value='AMBIENT'> AMBIENT</option><option  value='BREAKFAST'> BREAKFAST</option><option  value='BRUSH'> BRUSH</option><option  value='Confectionary'> Confectionary</option><option  value='DRESSING AND SAUCES'> DRESSING AND SAUCES</option><option  value='Free'> Free</option><option  value='KEELINGS JUICES'> KEELINGS JUICES</option><option  value='PACKAGING'> PACKAGING</option><option  value='SMOOTHIE'> SMOOTHIE</option><option  value='VEGETABLES'> VEGETABLES</option><option  value='WRAPS AND BREAD'> WRAPS AND BREAD</option></select></div>
            <br>
        <div class = "productcreate">
        <div data-html="true" class="producttooltip tooltip-custom" title="Enter in the correct cost price for the product above">?</div>
        <label style="font-size:14px" class="control-label"><font color="black"><strong>Cost Price</strong></font></label> <span class="required_field">   </span>
        <form autocomplete="off"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control-login" id="cost_price" name="cost_price" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this)"/>     <br/>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
  </div>
        <div>
            <label style="float:left; width: 40%; font-weight: bold; margin-top: -15px; margin-left: 42px; margin-bottom: 0px; color:black;">(Press Enter)</label>
            <label style="float:right; width: 40%; font-weight: bold; margin-top: -15px; margin-right: -120px; margin-bottom: 0px; color:black;">(Press Shift)</label>
        </div>
<div style="margin-left: 0.5px;"class="submitactions modal-footer content_container">
    <input disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" class="btn form-btns btn-primary ajax_forms_save_more" style="width: 24%; float: left; margin-right: 8px !important;" type="submit "id="customButtonSave" value="Save & New"/>
    <input disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" class="btn form-btns btn-primary ajax_forms_save"  style="width: 24%; float: right; margin-right: 8px !important;" id="customButton" value="Save & Close"/>

</div>
```

Then in a document.ready function, I have the following jQuery to check if text has been inputted

```
$('.productcreate input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;

    $('.productcreate input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('.submitactions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.submitactions input').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

The code works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't do anything in Safari. No errors come up in the console. I'm not sure what is the alternate solution to get this to work on all browsers? Does Safari fire triggers on different event? This is really my first time when I'm working with Safari so I am quite unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the below lines to ensure that helps you in safari browser:

```
$('.productcreate input').live('keyup',function() { ...

$('.productcreate input').on('keyup',function() {...
```

these lines support the safari brwoser.

Comment: I'll give these a go and see how I get on! Thank you

Comment: .live is no good since its not supported on Chrome and .on didn't make any difference. I'll do more debugging tomorrow and see if I can get anything through the console!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confused.

1) You could use `<button></button>` to submit, instead of with an input (preference)

2) You nested a `.each()` loop function inside of your event handler which does nothing except make your initial value into empty.

3) You can use the native `document.querySelector()` and `.addEventListener()` to bind functions to events.

Here is a working example:

```js
var othersCompleted = false;
var $submitButtons = $('.submitactions button');

$('.productcreate input').on('keyup', function(e) {
var $this = $(this);
var valueLength = this.value.length;

$this.siblings().each(function () {
    if (this.value.length > 0) { othersCompleted = true }
})

valueLength < 1 || othersCompleted === false ? $submitButtons.attr('disabled', 'disabled') : $submitButtons.attr('disabled', false)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productcreate">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 0.5px;"class="submitactions modal-footer content_container">
    <button disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" class="btn form-btns btn-primary ajax_forms_save_more" style="width: 24%; float: left; margin-right: 8px !important;" type="submit " id="customButtonSave">
      Save & New
    </button>
    <button disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" class="btn form-btns btn-primary ajax_forms_save"  style="width: 24%; float: right; margin-right: 8px !important;" id="customButton" />
    Save & Close
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have slightly adjusted my code to show the full form with input fields. The reason I used .each is because I have 2 divs with the same name in the form. Is that something that I should avoid?

Comment: Do you want it so that the user has to put text into the inputs to enable the `submit` buttons?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what my goal is with this code. If there is no text in both text fields, the buttons are disabled :)

Comment: @ArturL I understand now! I updated my code to enable the submit buttons only if both inputs have text in them. It is done by having an external variable which checks the other sibling inputs to see if they have text in them.

Comment: I think where my problem is coming from... I am getting error message in the console saying "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select[name='stocktake_id_sel_sales'". This is a select box loaded from an external file on every page. This error doesn't appear on Chrome or Firefox, only on Safari, therefore none of my jQuery works. Any suggestions why that could be?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot... $("select[name='stocktake_id_sel'") was missing the closing bracket, which was throwing an error and causing the whole jQuery to stop working. Chrome and Firefox seem to be smart enough to add/ignore it. Safari isn't... I "love" Apple!